# How to test LAN cables/connectivity without internet

Tags: networking, connection, lan, rj-45, cable-tester

We are planning to switch offices where each desk has a RJ45 plug, but we need to make sure the LAN works properly before making the step.

There is no access to the internet, all there is is a switch and the cables.

**What would be an efficient solution to test the LAN connectivity?**

- The minimum would be to know if all cables are correctly wired
- The LAN will be used for internet and phone
- A plus would be to know the speed / quality of the cables / LAN

Using D-Link components can be considered.

Thank you for your advises.

Comment: A LAN cable tester.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are simple low cost Ethernet testers out there that can check if the cable is correctly wired and verify connectivity. If you're interested in knowing the maximum speed and quality of the cables you will have to spend a lot of money - those kind of testers are expensive and not worth it if you only going to setup one network. Also just the status lights on the switch and NIC's can verify link up.

You can also use two computers between the cables to verify the connection and use [JPerf](https://code.google.com/p/xjperf/) to test the speed.